# Relative import in python packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

Following is my python package structure

```
PKG
|-->build
|-->dist
|-->src
|   |-->pkg
|   |   |-->data
|   |   |   |-->__init__.py
|   |   |   |-->module1.py
|   |   |-->dataset
|   |   |   |-->__init__.py
|   |   |   |-->module2.py
|   |   |-->__init__.py
|   |-->pkg.egg-info
|   |-->__init__.py
|-->__init__.py  
|-->LICENSE
|-->>README.md
|-->setup.py
```

I want to use some function of module1 in module2. So I tried

1. `from ..data import module1` which gave `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`
2. 

```
import sys 
sys.path.append('../../')
from data import module1
```

gave
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'`

At this point in time, I'm unsure on how to fix this.

Comment: Let me guess, you're running your script with `python3 path/to/module2.py`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly due to running `module2.py` as a script "raw", rather than executing it as a qualified module name rooted in `pkg`, e.g. running `python3 path/to/pkg/dataset/module2.py`. The problem with that is that it runs `module2.py` in such a way that it thinks itself a standalone script, it doesn't know it's "supposed" to be `pkg.dataset.module2` at all.

The correct solution is to, after installing the package (into system or user `site-packages`, or installing it into an active virtual environment), execute it in such a way that it *knows* its qualified name correctly, e.g.:

```
python3 -m pkg.dataset.module2
```

That tells Python to import the qualified module by looking it up in the module search path, through the parent packages, so it is run with the knowledge that it *is* in a package, and can therefore perform relative imports.

Comment: I'm still in the devleopment phase so does that mean I need to re-run ```setup.py``` and pip install the package everytime I want to test ```module2.py```? Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Any idea on why  ```from ..data import module1``` isn't working?

Comment: @Lawhatre: For hacky development needs, you could do stuff like (for `bash`) `export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/root/directory/below_pkg/in/src/tree`, so the source tree just below `pkg` is treated as a place to look for importable modules (if using something other than `bash`, an equivalent approach for that shell to set that environment variable). I don't recommend it for long term use, but for temporary use during development it's easy enough.

Comment: @Lawhatre: That's what I explained in the answer. `from ..data import module1` only works if `module2` knows that it is *really* `pkg.dataset.module2`. Run it the wrong way, and it thinks it is just `module2`, and there is no package hierarchy to navigate in the first place.

Comment: please give your comments on the answer I gave. Is it a ok to do that? Or have am I going wrong somewhere.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thank GOODNESS! I've been trying to understand this for so long, navigating from one non-answer to the next. Your answer is PERFECT, well done!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use sys.path.append("../")

Comment: tried. It also gives ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'data'```

Answer (score 0):

- In development phase

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/src')
from pkg.data import module1
```

- In deployment phase
  remove

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/src')
```

and just keep

```
from pkg.data import module1
```

Comment: This doesn't get the benefits of relative imports (in terms of of avoiding retyping potentially long names and needing to change them when a single layer in the tree changes names), and it requires the code to change between development and deployment, a generally terrible idea. That's why I was suggesting a solution that changes how you run it, while keeping the code the same.